# Large numbers of "relay access denied" from same sender with helo=<[127.0.0.1]>

Tags: postfix

I've noticed large numbers of these lines in our logs recently (where ourdomain.com is a domain we control and 14.242.x.x is an IP outside our network):

```
Oct 27 20:59:38 server postfix/smtpd[26781]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[14.242.x.x]: 454 4.7.1 <xxxx@yahoo.com>: Relay access denied; from=<a-user@ourdomain.com> to=<xxxx@yahoo.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<[127.0.0.1]>
```

They appear to be sent from localhost. How can I track down the source of these attempts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These attempts are coming from 14.242.x.x. - The helo bit can be ignored as that what the remote mail server is claiming (unlike the IP address which is recorded by your server).

The relay access denied is presumably because they are trying to send email externally from an unknown address and without appropriate authorisation from your mail server.

I'd its a concern, you may want to install fail2ban to temporarily firewall traffic from these IOs to discourage them.

Comment: Thanks. I'll see if I can get fail2ban to deal with it as about 80% of the logs are full of these lines.